# Laravel validate passed data and prevent user changes

Tags: php, laravel

I asked this question before and didn't get accurate answer, as I know its impossible to prevent users from changing value using `inspect element`, but if I used form with `{{ csrf_field() }}` the user still can `inspect element` and change the value of `id` as example.
and well, to validate data as some said, these data will be pass to the controller and there will validate it, but this is will be ok if the controller received `id=2` instead of `1`, so user can change the `id` from `inspect element`, do you have any solution for this?

**example (I'm using ajax to pass data to controller)**

```
 <form role="form" name="form_address" id="form_address" action="" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
  @foreach($stores as $store)
   <input class="field" id="id" hidden="" value="{{$store->store_id}}">
    <input class="field" id="price" value="{{$store->store_price}}">
      @endforeach

  </form>
   <button id="save_data" ><span class="BigButton_text">Save</span>
```

Comment: do you want to submit a value/data with the form and you don't the user to be able to change this value/data?

Comment: yes thats what I want, I tried many way but still can change

Comment: try using `session_start();`  `$_session['mydata']='thedata';` then on the ajax side call `session_start();` again then you can grab your data from `$_session['mydata'];` but even this is not full proof still find a way to perform verifications on the processing script.

Comment: then in some cases but i would not recommend this you can also use `<input hidden readonly type="number" name="mydata" value="thedata"></input>` nested in side the form but this can be manipulated also. key is in validating all user inputs every thing has an Achilles' heel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obfuscate the id by making them non-sequential numbers.

There is a **Laravel** package dedicated to this approach:

https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-FakeId

This package generates prime numbers instead of random strings, it is quite faster that way.

This package will encode and decode the primary id value of the model.

This process is automated when using this package, as there are two othe similar packages to this but with much less automation:

https://github.com/cybercog/laravel-optimus

https://github.com/jenssegers/optimus

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Laravel.

As a user said, you should do the validation on the backend.

First, for security, **don't show increments let IDs** for users (that will make it prone to guessing - a user changing the store ID to try to edit another record, for example)

On the backend there are several ways to do this validation.

You can add a [Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization), or it could be as simple as:

1. Getting the logged in user ID, like this:

   ```php
   $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
   ```
2. making sure the `user` owns the store (get the store he sent the `request`, and check if the user `id` is the same?) Depends on your architecture.

Comment: here what I want not for logged users!!! I mean by user any one on the website not those who are logging

Comment: Well then my friend, the problem is your architecture.
If you don't want the user to change the `store_id`, consider using a named route like `stores/my-store/products` for example.

That way, you're not passing the data on the form, you're passing it either dynamically (passing the store slug on the request name) or fixed.

Comment: didn't get what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

If the user changes the store id via the inspect element, you can apply something like the following in the controller or middleware:

```
if (! in_array($request->store_id, Auth::user()->stores->pluck('id')->toArray()) {
    abort('403');
}
```

Much better than this is to get acquainted with the **Authorization** service provided by Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

I will suggest for you to write a few **Gates** and put them to action. That's what I did when I was in the same position as you are now.

By doing that, quickly you'll realize how feasible it is to guard your applicaion from data tampering via the inspect element.

Comment: I mean by user not logged user, my website works for non logged users